# Use of stream, filter and average on list and jdk8

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have this list of data that look like this;

```
{id, datastring}

{1,"a:1|b:2|d:3"}
{2,"a:2|c:2|c:4"}
{3,"a:2|bb:2|a:3"}
{4,"a:3|e:2|ff:3"}
```

What I need to do here is to do operations like average or find all id for which a element in the string is less than a certain value.

Here are some example;

Averages

```
{a,2}{b,2}{bb,2}{c,3}{d,3}{e,2}{ff,3}
```

Find all id's where c<4

```
{2}
```

Find all id's where a<3

```
{1,2,3}
```

Would this be a good use of stream() and filter() ??

Comment: Yes. It would be. (if I got it right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you have your answer, but here are my versions too :

```
 Map<String, Double> result = list.stream()
            .map(Data::getElements)
            .flatMap((Multimap<String, Integer> map) -> {
                return map.entries().stream();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.averagingInt((Entry<String, Integer> token) -> {
                        return token.getValue();
                    })));
    System.out.println(result);

    List<Integer> result2 = list.stream()
            .filter((Data data) -> {
                return data.getElements().get("c").stream().anyMatch(i -> i < 4);
            })
            .map(Data::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use stream operations to achieve that but I would suggest to create a class for this datas, so that each row corresponds to one specific instance. That will make your life easier IMO.

```
class Data {
    private int id;
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> map;
    ....
}
```

That said let's take a look at how you could implement this. First, the find all's implementation:

```
public static Set<Integer> ids(List<Data> list, String value, Predicate<Integer> boundPredicate) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(d -> d.getMap().containsKey(value))
               .filter(d -> d.getMap().get(value).stream().anyMatch(boundPredicate))
               .map(d -> d.getId())
               .collect(toSet());
}
```

This one is simple to read. You get a `Stream<Data>` from the list. Then you apply a filter such that you only get instances that have the value given in the map, and that there is a value which satisfies the predicate you give. Then you map each instance to its corresponding id and you collect the resulting stream in a Set.

Example of call:

```
Set<Integer> set = ids(list, "a", value -> value < 3);
```

which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

The average request was a bit more tricky. I ended up with another implementation, you finally get a `Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics>` at the end (which does contain the average) but also other informations.

```
Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> stats = list.stream()
                .flatMap(d -> d.getMap().entrySet().stream())
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                               e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).summaryStatistics(),
                               (i1, i2) -> {i1.combine(i2); return i1;}));
```

You first get a `Stream<Data>`, then you `flatMap` each entry set of each map to have `Stream<Entry<String, List<Integer>>`. Now you collect this stream into a map for which each key is mapped by the entry's key and each `List<Integer>` is mapped by its corresponding `IntSummaryStatistics` value. If you have two identical keys, you combine their respective `IntSummaryStatistics` values.

Given you data set, you get a `Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics>`

```
ff => IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=3, min=3, average=3.000000, max=3}
bb => IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=2, min=2, average=2.000000, max=2}
a => IntSummaryStatistics{count=5, sum=11, min=1, average=2.200000, max=3}
b => IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=2, min=2, average=2.000000, max=2}
c => IntSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=6, min=2, average=3.000000, max=4}
d => IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=3, min=3, average=3.000000, max=3}
e => IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=2, min=2, average=2.000000, max=2}
```

from which you can easily grab the average.

---

Here's a full [working example](https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/c83763f939129d3c4036), the implementation can certainly be improved though.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I just gave it a try and it really seem to do what I expected. I will study it more in depth tomorrow as it has a lot of new stuff that I am not yet familiar yet..

Comment: Note that you could avoid one lookup by using `getOrDefault` in place of two `filter`: `stream().filter(d -> d.getMap().getOrDefault(id, emptyList()).stream().anyMatch(predicate)).map(...)`

Comment: Hi Alexis,

How would I replace the Files.lines() load by the output of an sqlResults?

sqlResult of type java.sql.ResultSet

I am not familiar with the .map and .collect(toList())

thanks

Comment: where/how do you define "emptyList()" ?

Comment: @AndreCouture Hi, for the ResultSet part, you can check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html. Basically a while loop and then you add a new Data object in  a list. `emptyList()` is just a static method in the `Collections` class that returns an empty list. Also since you get these datas from a DB, maybe it's simpler to do what you want with SQL queries directly? It will also be more performant. Or it is just to pratcie with the new java 8 features?

Comment: I'm not convinced that doing this string manipulation in Oracle would be more efficient. Also I really wanted to practice with the new java 8 features. They seem very powerful as well as producing much cleaner and compact code. Also, once the list is in memory we can then manipulate it in any ways we want as oppose to doing another query every times as hibernate will probably not be able to use caching as parameters changes.

Comment: Here is my [modified version](https://gist.github.com/nomade1999/f191d5fe0dca4c1aa7d2). What I would like here is the same as before but also allow to operate on the ConfScore as well. Note that we only require to filter on one at a time.

Comment: I want to be able to work on the pronscore or confscore like returning all IDs that have a confscore marching my criterias

Comment: Also averages of confscore the same way as for the other one. Now my problem is that map only seem to take 2 params.

Comment: It seem that I cannot write on the chat "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq." ..